# Dot Net Highcharts Series Color

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Does anyone have a working example of using the new Dot Net Highcharts wrapper and changing the series colour? I just cant get it to change for the life of me, think I must have changed every single color property going. None of them default from the normal palette.

```
@(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
new Highcharts
{
    Title = new Title
    {
        Text = "Picks Grouped By Target And Week Of Year"

    },

    XAxis = new List<XAxis>
    {
        new XAxis
        {
            Categories = WeeksOfYear.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString())
        }
    },
    YAxis = new List<YAxis>
    {
        new YAxis
        {
            Min = 0,
            Title = new YAxisTitle
            {
                Text = "Number of picks"
            },
            StackLabels = new YAxisStackLabels
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Style = new Hashtable
                {
                    { "fontWeght", "bold" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Legend = new Legend
    {
        Align = LegendAlign.Right,
        X = -30,
        VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Top,
        Y = 25,
        Floating = true,
        BorderColor = "#CCC",
        BorderWidth = 1,
        BackgroundColor = "white"

    },
    Tooltip = new Tooltip
    {
        Formatter = "formatToolTip"
    },
    PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
    {
        Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
        {

            Stacking = PlotOptionsColumnStacking.Normal,
            DataLabels = new PlotOptionsColumnDataLabels
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Color = "#FFFFFF",

                Shadow = new Shadow()
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    Color = "black",
                    Width = 10,
                    OffsetX = 0,
                    OffsetY = 0
                }
            }
        }
    },

    Series = new List<Series>
    {
        new ColumnSeries
        {
            Name = "Over 45 Min",
            Data = @ViewData["StackedColumnOver45Min"] as List<ColumnSeriesData>

    },
        new ColumnSeries
        {
            Name = "Under 45 Min",
            Data = @ViewData["StackedColumnUnder45Min"] as List<ColumnSeriesData>

        }
    }
}
, "WeekOfYearSlaStackedColumn")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series color could be set in series as explained in [API reference for .NET Highcharts](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_column_series.html#a6cc5527425d1836bdcd43f66069c11a3).

```
...
Series = new List<Series>
{
    new ColumnSeries
    {
        Color = "rgba(165,170,217,1)",
        ...
```

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work. First thing I tried :( happy to be corrected but not working on this end.

Comment: @KaiserSozei87 Have you tried with the most recent version of the .NET Highcharts and Highcharts (v5.0.11)?

Comment: I only bought it within the last month with the .NET wrapper so yes i'm pretty sure it's all the latest and greatest (not at dev machine atm to check)

Comment: I have tested this code and it was working, also there's and online demo created using .NET wrapper showing how colors could be set: http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=ColumnPlacement&theme=default Maybe you could provide a full and minimal file required to recreate the problem?

Comment: no if you say its working then I must have gone wrong somewhere. I'll re-visit the code and take a look. Will message on here if I still have problems. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Found my issue!  I initially installed Highcharts.NET via nuget package.  That does not come with the js files, css files, or any of that.  They expect you to use the versions available online.  My target environments don't have access to those sites, so I copied the files into my project and referenced them locally.  The version of highcharts I downloaded came with 2 different copies of of the js libraries, a copy in the "code" folder and a copy in the "code\js" folder.  I was referencing the copies in the "code\js" folder.  As soon as I change to the copies in the "code" folder it worked!

Answer (score 0):

for setting colors (anywhere in Highcharts in asp.net) you should use this construction:

```
using System.Drawing;

Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DFEEB2"),
```